# How to write a bit mask in python for clean bits between index j and i?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, bit

I want to get a bit mask to clean a bit sting between index j to i.

In Java I know something like

```
int allOnes = ~0;
int left = allOnes << (j + 1);
int right = ((i<<j) - 1);
int mask = left | right;
```

How to implement these in Python?

Comment: It's the same operation, so just use the equivalent bitwise operators for python?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using bit-shifting, it might be easier to simply add together the relevant powers of two. Say you want the eighth to twelfth least significant bits. Then you'd do

```
>>> i = 8
>>> j = 12
>>> mask = sum(2**x for x in range(i-1, j-1))
>>> bin(mask)
'0b11110000000'
```

And then you can use this to mask actual numbers:

```
>>> num = 0b110100111100001101100110101
                            ^^^^
>>> bin(num & mask)
'0b1100000000'
   ^^^
```

The leading `0` is, of course, omitted

Comment: its often faster in python to convert to a string and just use slicing (+1 though I think this is great)

Answer (score 2):

i recommend converting to a string and slicing instead of masking.... in my experience its often faster

```
x = 5233513423
print(int(bin(x)[2:][3:7],2))
```

although this will just give you the bits your interested in

(ie if you actually wanted the result to be `0b11011000`(or whatever) instead of just `0b11011`  you will need to manually shift some bits)

Comment: It sounds like the questioner is looking to (create a mask to) unset the relevant bits, not retrieve them.

Comment: sure but usually thats mostly to isolate relevant bits ... but i cant speak to the OP's use case, and they may indeed need actual masking

Answer (score 1):

Same code, just remove int and it will work

```
allOnes = ~0;
left = allOnes << (j + 1);
right = ((i<<j) - 1);
mask = left | right;
```